# Laradock connect external postgre using ssh tunnel

Tags: postgresql, ssh, ssh-tunnel, laradock

I need to connect a DB using ssh tunnel.
I run the command (`ssh -i .ssh/id_rsa -N -L 19512:127.0.0.1:9512 root@server`) and setting up de db config in .env file.

But I don't really know where run the command, I try on my linux console (not in docker), and on workspace container, but doesn't make the connection.

Is that possible to use external DB from a laradock docker container?